# Listview with Textview and 2 Edittext in a single row in android

Tags: android, listview

I want to have a single "Textview" and  2 "Edittext" in a single row.I have tried the following code:

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

   >


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/vegtext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
       />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/vegquantity"   
        android:hint="Qty"    
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

     <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/vegprice"       
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:hint="price"
        android:layout_weight="1"
       />


</LinearLayout>
```

Getview in adapter:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
         VeglistHolder holder;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(convertview == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertview  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.veglistrow, null); 

             holder = new VeglistHolder();

             holder.text = (TextView) convertview
                        .findViewById(R.id.vegtext);


             holder.Qtyedit = (EditText) convertview
                        .findViewById(R.id.vegquantity);

             holder.priceedit = (EditText) convertview
                        .findViewById(R.id.vegprice);


             convertview.setTag(holder);            

        }
        else
        {
            holder = (VeglistHolder) convertview.getTag();      
        }



         holder.text.setText(vegitems[position]);
        return convertview;
    }
```

But the Edittext is not there in the row. Also some blank space is coming below the "TExtview" .I searched for "Lots of" post regarding this but i cant solve this.Please help me to solve this..Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try setting the width of your edit text to fill_parent since you are using layout_weight

Comment: On a sidenote, having an edittext box in a list item is a really bad idea. It can slow down your listview like hell

Comment: Thanks  user603125...Can you suggest good idea to have that..

Comment: @Subburaj change the edittext to textview. On clicking the list item you can display a dialog box with edittext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your problem is that you set the width and the height of the `TextView` to `fill parent`

Comment: well thats the problem by makeing it fill_parent it takes up the whole UI and it doesnt give the EditText any place to appear. You should set the height and the width of your TextView to wrap_content or some value instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use weightSum in main layout for equal partition as below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="3"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: Please give your textView and editText property  android:layout_weight="1" for each.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Realative layout. Modify the attributes to suit your requirement

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="60dp" //set to whatever you desire
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="60dp"// //set to whatever you desire
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

</RelativeLayout>
```